# browsers ignoring port in rewrite rule after first connection

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, browser

This is a bit of an esoteric config, but I hope someone out there has figured this one out.  Web server (apache httpd) is running three http virtualhosts based on port (80, 8080, and 9876) and three https virtualhosts (443, 8443, and 9443).  The http virtualhosts are configured via rewrite rule to redirect to the https port: 80 goes to 443, 8080 to 8443 and 9876 to 9443.  The rewrite rule looks something like this in the virtualhost for port 8080:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://myhost.example.com:8443/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The rewrite for port 80 works properly all the time.  For the non-standard ports (8080 and 9876), however things get odd.  If I use wget, I see this get redirected properly.  On the first connection from a browser, the redirect works for 8080.  On subsequent connections to http://myhost.example.com:8080 the browser is redirecting to https://myhost.example.com:8080 rather than the correct port of 8443.  The same behavior is happening on port 9876 as well.  Any ideas on what's going on here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider using `mod_proxy` instead. You can also combine `RewriteRule`s with it so you can choose which URLs go to which back-end. Then the user never sees the non-standard ports.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, if I could do that, I would.  This is a fairly well established system (users have the http urls), so I need to keep the initial http ports as is and redirect the users to the https ports (the https ports are newly configured).

Comment: If they're only accessing the unusual ports in a browser (as opposed to having them hard-coded into another system/app), you just point the old ports to the one vhost, 301 redirect requests to each old port to the corresponding new URL. You can use a new set of ports for your back-ends when proxying.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I'll check if that'll work for our users.  Speaking of vhosts, we could also get cnames setup in DNS which could be used for the sites on the non-standard ports (they could all use the standard ssl port that way just separate named vhosts).  It'll mean a couple of extra alt names in the ssl cert, but it's another option at least.  Thanks for bouncing ideas around.

Comment: No worries. I would avoid using more than (sub)domain unless your users truly *need* to access to the back-ends, directly.